# Hide "Python" on Task Manager

Tags: python, process, taskmanager

I have python program and this is compiled file(.pyc)
I wrote Launcher with C#. This launcher starts this Python program (pyc file).
But as you see in picture, my python program's top name is "Python", how can i hide this Python?
Thanks.
C# Launch python code:

```
 private bool ProcessCalistir(string path, string Args = "", bool wait = false)
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        //proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = PythonKlasor;
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Args;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        proc.Start();
        if (wait) proc.WaitForExit();
        return true;
    }
```

ProcessCalistir("python.exe", "MyPythonProgram.pyc");

[image]